# How to move files using partial file name?

Tags: excel, vba

I learnt how to copy multiple files from a single folder to multiple folders depending on file name in Excel sheet.

```vb
Sub MoveSelectedfiles()

    Dim FSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim fl As Scripting.File
    Dim sourcefldr As Scripting.Folder
    Dim destinationFldr As Scripting.Folder
    Dim index As Integer
    Dim lastrow As Integer
    
    Set FSO = New FileSystemObject
    Set sourcefldr = FSO.GetFolder("E:\Testing\Source")
    Set destinationFldr = FSO.GetFolder("E:\Testing\Destination")
    
    lastrow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
                
    For index = 2 To 10
    
        If (FSO.FileExists(sourcefldr.Path & "\" & Sheet1.Range("A" & index).Value)) Then
            FSO.MoveFile sourcefldr.Path & "\" & Sheet1.Range("A" & index).Value, destinationFldr.Path & "\"
        End If
     
    Next index
     
End Sub
```

I have to define the exact file name. I would like to write even half/incomplete file name.

E.g. If a file name is "Excel training makes easy" and in the Excel sheet I write "Excel training".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Move Files From a List of Partial File Names

- You can use the `Dir` function with wild characters (`*` and `?`) to test if a file exists, e.g.:

  **Begins with**

  ```
  sFileName = Dir(sFolderPath & sPartialFileName & "*")
  ```

  **Contains**

  ```
  sFileName = Dir(sFolderPath & "*" & sPartialFileName & "*")
  ```

  Then you can continue with:

  ```
  if len(sFileName) > 0 Then ' source file found
  ```

**Partial File Names**

```vb
Sub MoveFilesFromListPartial()
    
    Const sPath As String = "E:\Testing\Source"
    Const dPath As String = "E:\Testing\Destination"
    Const fRow As Long = 2
    Const Col As String = "A"
    
    ' Reference the worksheet.
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheet1
    
    ' Calculate the last row,
    ' i.e. the row containing the last non-empty cell in the column.
    Dim lRow As Long: lRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Row
                
    ' Validate the last row.
    If lRow < fRow Then
        MsgBox "No data in column range.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Early Binding - needs a reference
    ' to 'Tools > References > Microsoft Scripting Runtime' (has intelli-sense)
    Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    ' Late Binding - needs no reference (no intelli-sense)
    'Dim fso As Object: Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    ' Validate the source folder path.
    Dim sFolderPath As String: sFolderPath = sPath
    If Right(sFolderPath, 1) <> "\" Then sFolderPath = sFolderPath & "\"
    If Not fso.FolderExists(sFolderPath) Then
        MsgBox "The source folder path '" & sFolderPath _
            & "' doesn't exist.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Validate the destination folder path.
    Dim dFolderPath As String: dFolderPath = dPath
    If Right(dFolderPath, 1) <> "\" Then dFolderPath = dFolderPath & "\"
    If Not fso.FolderExists(dFolderPath) Then
        MsgBox "The destination folder path '" & dFolderPath _
            & "' doesn't exist.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim r As Long ' current row in worksheet column
    Dim sFilePath As String
    Dim sPartialFileName As String
    Dim sFileName As String
    Dim dFilePath As String
    Dim sYesCount As Long ' source file moved
    Dim sNoCount As Long ' source file not found
    Dim dYesCount As Long ' source file exists in destination folder
    Dim BlanksCount As Long ' blank cell
    
    For r = fRow To lRow
        sPartialFileName = CStr(ws.Cells(r, Col).Value)
        If Len(sPartialFileName) > 0 Then ' the cell is not blank
            ' 'Begins with' sPartialFileName
            sFileName = Dir(sFolderPath & sPartialFileName & "*")
            ' or instead, 'Contains' sPartialFileName
            'sFileName = Dir(sFolderPath & "*" & sPartialFileName & "*")
            If Len(sFileName) > 0 Then ' source file found
                sFilePath = sFolderPath & sFileName
                dFilePath = dFolderPath & sFileName
                If Not fso.FileExists(dFilePath) Then ' the source file...
                    fso.MoveFile sFilePath, dFilePath ' ... doesn't exist...
                    sYesCount = sYesCount + 1 ' ... in the destination
                Else ' the source file exists in the destination folder
                    dYesCount = dYesCount + 1
                End If
            Else ' the source file doesn't exist
                sNoCount = sNoCount + 1
            End If
        Else ' the cell is blank
            BlanksCount = BlanksCount + 1
        End If
    Next r
 
    MsgBox "Stats" & vbLf _
        & "Source files moved: " & sYesCount & vbLf _
        & "Source files not found: " & sNoCount & vbLf _
        & "Source files existed in destination: " & dYesCount & vbLf _
        & "Number of blank cells: " & BlanksCount & vbLf _
        & "Number of cells processed: " & lRow - fRow + 1, _
        vbInformation
 
End Sub
```

**Full File Names**

```
Sub MoveFilesFromList()
    
    Const sPath As String = "E:\Testing\Source"
    Const dPath As String = "E:\Testing\Destination"
    Const fRow As Long = 2
    Const Col As String = "A"
    
    ' Reference the worksheet.
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheet1
    
    ' Calculate the last row,
    ' i.e. the row containing the last non-empty cell in the column.
    Dim lRow As Long: lRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Row
                
    ' Validate the last row.
    If lRow < fRow Then
        MsgBox "No data in column range.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Early Binding - needs a reference
    ' to 'Tools > References > Microsoft Scripting Runtime' (has intelli-sense)
    Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    ' Late Binding - needs no reference (no intelli-sense)
    'Dim fso As Object: Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    ' Validate the source folder path.
    Dim sFolderPath As String: sFolderPath = sPath
    If Right(sFolderPath, 1) <> "\" Then sFolderPath = sFolderPath & "\"
    If Not fso.FolderExists(sFolderPath) Then
        MsgBox "The source folder path '" & sFolderPath _
            & "' doesn't exist.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Validate the destination folder path.
    Dim dFolderPath As String: dFolderPath = dPath
    If Right(dFolderPath, 1) <> "\" Then dFolderPath = dFolderPath & "\"
    If Not fso.FolderExists(dFolderPath) Then
        MsgBox "The destination folder path '" & dFolderPath _
            & "' doesn't exist.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim r As Long ' current row in worksheet column
    Dim sFilePath As String
    Dim sFileName As String
    Dim dFilePath As String
    Dim sYesCount As Long ' source file moved
    Dim sNoCount As Long ' source file doesn't exist
    Dim dYesCount As Long ' source file exists in destination folder
    Dim BlanksCount As Long ' blank cell
    
    For r = fRow To lRow
        sFileName = CStr(ws.Cells(r, Col).Value)
        If Len(sFileName) > 0 Then ' the cell is not blank
            sFilePath = sFolderPath & sFileName
            If fso.FileExists(sFilePath) Then ' the source file exists
                dFilePath = dFolderPath & sFileName
                If Not fso.FileExists(dFilePath) Then ' the source file...
                    fso.MoveFile sFilePath, dFilePath ' ... doesn't exist...
                    sYesCount = sYesCount + 1 ' ... in the destination folder
                Else ' the source file exists in the destination folder
                    dYesCount = dYesCount + 1
                End If
            Else ' the source file doesn't exist
                sNoCount = sNoCount + 1
            End If
        Else ' the cell is blank
            BlanksCount = BlanksCount + 1
        End If
    Next r
 
    MsgBox "Stats" & vbLf _
        & "Source files moved: " & sYesCount & vbLf _
        & "Source files don't exist: " & sNoCount & vbLf _
        & "Source files existed in destination: " & dYesCount & vbLf _
        & "Number of blank cells: " & BlanksCount & vbLf _
        & "Number of cells processed: " & lRow - fRow + 1, _
        vbInformation
 
End Sub
```